# JMeter Distributed Runner not able to Generate the Consolidated Reports

Tags: performance, jmeter

When I am running a simple standalone JMeter script using command line as below

```
jmeter -n -t your_script.jmx
```

This generates a CSV file which contains all the data related to the execution.

However, when the same JMeter file executed for a distributed load testing with multiple JMeter Server IP addresses which will simulate the given number of users and runs on the target server, I am not able to get the `jmeter.csv`file Generated(But the command runs successfully).

The command I have used for distributed execution is

```
jmeter -n -t script.jmx -R IP_address1, IP_address2,...
```

Now, I should get a consolidated `jmeter.csv` file from this execution. But, I am not getting one.

Same is the case with JMeter API `DistributedRunner Class`- We are not getting the consolidated `jmeter.csv` file and reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command:

> jmeter -n -t your_script.jmx

**does not generate any CSV file**, you need to add [`-l` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) and provide desired results file location like:

```
jmeter -n -t your_script.jmx -l jmeter.csv
```

The same applies for distributed testing:

```
jmeter -n -t script.jmx -R IP_address1, IP_address2 -l jmeter.csv
```

If you provide `-l` command-line argument but still not getting any results most probably your script execution fails on remote slaves somewhere somehow. Follow the below checklist in order to get to the bottom of the script failure:

- Inspect `jmeter.log` file on master machine and `jmeter-server.log` on the remote slaves, if something goes wrong - most probably you will find the cause in [log files](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)
- Make sure that [JRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine#Java_Runtime_Environment) version is the same on master and the slaves
- Make sure that JMeter version is the same on master and the slaves, it's [recommended to use the latest JMeter version where possible](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version)
- If the test relies on any of the [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) - make to install them all onto all slave machines. The plugins can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)
- If your test is using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) - you will need to copy the CSV file to all slaves manually
- If your test needs any additional JMeter Properties you will need to [supply the properties via -J or -D command-line arguments on all the machines or via -G command-line arugment on the master](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)